# formatting text output in terminals

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently writing a command line tool for myself, that needs to print some information on the terminal. I'm a little annoyed of the whole formatting. Here is my example.

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = '%(message)s')

console_logger = logging.getLogger("console_logger")
console_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_logger_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

console_logger_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

console_logger.addHandler(console_logger_handler)
console_logger.propagate = False
```

here goes some further code and then I have the printing function

```
for element in open_orders:
    console_logger.info("Type: {}, Rate: {}, amount: {}, state: {}, pair: {}/{}, creation: {}, id: {}".format(element.type,
                                                      element.rate,
                                                      element.amount,
                                                      element.state,
                                                      element.currency_pair.get_base_currency().upper(),
                                                      element.currency_pair.get_quote_currency().upper(),
                                                      creation_time,
                                                      element.order_id))
```

I rather would like to have this as a column where the output is aligned at the colon. after each `element` a line of underscores or minusses would be nice as well, this should respect terminal width. I know this can be hardcoded in some manner, but isn't there a better way? Some kind of templating engine that can handle multiline output?

EDIT:
So here is an example:

```
Type        :        buy
Rate        :       1234
amount      :          1
state       :     active
pair        :    usd/eur
creation    : 2017.12.12
```

I know this can be printed line by line with `format` but I need to determine the length of the longest string on my own and I was wondering if there isn a framework or something more elegant doing this for me.
    id          :     123456

Comment: add an expected example in your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I finally found which helps a lot at least in case of lists and formatting of them is this 
[terminaltable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables)

Answer (score 0):

Use [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), add with your data :

```
for element in open_orders:
    console_logger.info("Type: {:25s}, Rate: {:25s}, amount: {:07.2f}, state: {:25s}, pair: {:25s}/{:25s}, creation: {:25s}, id: {:25s}".format(element.type,
                                                      element.rate,
                                                      element.amount,
                                                      element.state,
                                                      element.currency_pair.get_base_currency().upper(),
                                                      element.currency_pair.get_quote_currency().upper(),
                                                      creation_time,
                                                      element.order_id))
```

You can also visit this site : https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could try to use [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama).

You have to install it, tipically, from pypi.

It allows you to handle ***cursor positioning***, so you can control in which position at the screen (terminal) you want to print data, using "coordinates". Also, you can apply colors to text, which could give you a *cleaner* and *prettier* look if you want to.